# What is the spanish translation for "Account" when referring to a user account on a website?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, definiciones, vocabulario

The [English > Spanish](http://translate.google.com/#en|es|Account) translation  of *account* on [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com) comes up with various forms of the word `cuenta`.

However, the [Spanish > English](http://translate.google.com/#es|en|Cuenta) translation of `cuenta` returns words relating to financial transactions.

The word I want refers to account information that you might find on a website, such as username and password.

**For example:** Google account, Facebook account, Twitter account, etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## English

In this context, the word `account` could be translated as `cuenta`. One could use it in expressions such as `cuenta de usuario` (*user account*), `cuenta de Facebook`, `cuenta de Google`, and `cuenta de Twitter`.

**Examples of Usage:**

- [Cuentas de Google](https://accounts.google.com/Login?hl=es)
- [Twitter en español](https://twitter.com/#!/twitter_es)

---

## Español

La palabra `account` en este contexto se traduce como `cuenta`. Se dice `cuenta de usuario` (*user account*), `cuenta de Facebook`, `cuenta de Google` y `cuenta de Twitter`.

**Ejemplos:**

- [Cuentas de Google](https://accounts.google.com/Login?hl=es)
- [Twitter en español](https://twitter.com/#!/twitter_es)

Answer (score 3):

Si, no te preocupes. Se dice *cuenta*.

En inglés, tambien se usa "account" para decir una cuenta de usuario y una cuenta de banco. Es lo mismo en español.

Otra forma  de usar "cuenta" en español es "darse cuenta' = to realize (literally: to give account).

Por ejemplo:

"no me di cuenta" = "I didn't realize"